# How to use line breaker?

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uitextview, line-breaks

I have a dictionary app. There are 2 textViews. In the first I type a word and in the second a translation appears. But the problem is when I type something like this:

```
qwerty.
haha.
```

The answer in the second view appears in the following form:

```
qwerty.haha.
```

Without dots the same thing.

Assume,for example my string is

```
NSString *smthing=@"qwerty.\nhaha."
```

How can I replace "\n" with the line break?

Comment: `\n` is a line break. Show your real code.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
str1 = @"qwerty."

str2 = @"haha."

[NSString StringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@",str1,str2];
```

Comment: This is no different than simply having: `@"qwerty.\nhaha.";`.